# Put a dictionary into list

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I have code that should:

1. read file name and save it to list
2. open this files and save the content into list with list.

For example:

```
list=['filename1','filename2','filename3']
```

Then: `'filename1'` - should be a dictionary that contains all its content. Files look like: 
`'abc'` `'123'` 
 `'cde'` `'456'`

How properly put the dictionary into list, so i can
call it with `list[0]` etc.

My code is:

```
def getServerVersion(dirpath):
    global dictname
    dicktlist = os.listdir(path)
    arr_len = len(dictname)
    for i in range(arr_len):
        dictvalue = []
        str = ''.join(dirpath) + dictname[i]
        with open(str) as f:
             dictvalue[i]=dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)
    print(dicktlist)
```

instead of what it gives me list `[{key:value},{key:value}]`. So I need this list to store objects. How to do it?

Comment: Your function does not return anything. Is this intentional?

Comment: It looks like your problem is not how to put a dictionary into a list, but rather how to create a dictionary in the first place, right? If appending to a list is your problem, well, use [append](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Comment: Dicktlist? Hehe

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are starting with a list of filenames and want to end up with a list of dictionaries where for each dictionary in the list there is one key corresponding to a filename whose value is the contents of the associated file.  If that is correct then one way to do that would be to approach it this way:

```
filenames = ["file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt"]

filecontents = []

for a_filename in filenames:
    with open(a_filename) as f:
        contents = f.read()
    filecontents.append({filename: contents})
```